# get the output of a command line script as a template variable

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I need a help.

I've a working application (legacy) and I'm trying to add a new page in dev machine to make run some scripts so the designers don't have to do a ssh login.

I want it to run the script and return it's outputs to the html page, so I've done this:

url.py:

```
url(r'^DEVUpdate', 'myviewa.views.devUpdate'),
```

In the view:

```
def devUpdate(request):
    response = os.popen('./update.sh').read()
    print response
    return render_to_response('aux/update.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request));
```

And in the html:

```
Response:
{{ response }}
```

The output when I go to DEVUpdate page is, in my machine:

```
sh: 1: ./update.sh: not found
```

but in the html:

```
Response:
```

How do I get the value of response in html?

PD: I want to see the message ' sh: 1: ./update.sh: not found' in the html page

Comment: The path to udpate.sh is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the directory structure?

Comment: If the path is not wrong, what is the content?  The shell script might not run.

Comment: well the path is wrong, true, but I want to see the message  ./update.sh: not found in the html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.popen` returns the output of the command on stdout. An error message like that goes to stderr, so you won't get it.

Besides, os.popen is deprecated, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) say. Instead, use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
import subprocess

try:
    # stderr=subprocess.STDOUT combines stdout and stderr
    # shell=True is needed to let the shell search for the file
    # and give an error message, otherwise Python does it and
    # raises OSError if it doesn't exist.
    response = subprocess.check_output(
        "./update.sh", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    # It returned an error status
    response = e.output
```

Lastly, if `update.sh` takes more than a couple of seconds or so, it should probably be a background task called by Celery. Now the whole command has to finish before Django gives a response. But that's not related to the question.

Comment: You might want to add that the full path of the script should be passed.

Comment: I think he knows that, his question is about catching the error in the response variable.

Comment: I was referring to this: `sh: 1: ./update.sh: not found`

Comment: Yes, that's the exact error message that ends up in `response` this way, and it'll show up in his template. He's not asking how to fix it.

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass response in context:

```
return render_to_response('aux/update.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request, {'response': response});
```

Right now you try to access response from template but you don't pass it in context

Comment: sholudn't locals() do that?

Comment: well... maybe, frankly i don't know, i didn't ever use it, though explicite passing should work nevertheless

Comment: The annoying about this is that when I do a print of locals() it shows 'response':''. So , i have the response variable but not the value :(